# How do I make the peripheral of a BLE connection request a PHY update to 2M PHY?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Parameters like connection interval can be changed by changing files like conn_min_interval.
The value in this file is then used for negotiating the connection interval between the central and peripheral.

Is there an equivalent file for changing the preferred **LE PHY** to **2M PHY** or **Coded PHY**?

From this I imagine the peripheral would trigger a **PHY update request**.

I have found plenty of documentation on what 2M PHY and Coded PHY are, but no documentation on how to actually enable them.

(I'm using BlueZ with devices that both support 2M PHY and Coded PHY)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem connecting Linux BLUEZ with an nrf5340 SoC.
After some research, I've found a way to set the PHY using hcitool.

Using BLUEZ as a central, it is possible, after having established a connection, to change the PHY dynamically.

You can use the "hcitool" to modify the connection parameters and PHY by issuing raw HCI commands. The commands syntax may be extrapolated by analyzing source files like *"include/zephyr/bluetooth/hci.h"* file of the zephyr OS.
The HCI command 0x08 0x0032 is a BLE command to change the preferred PHY in an active connection.

This is the command declaration and its structure defined in the file "hci.h":

```
#define BT_HCI_OP_LE_SET_PHY                    BT_OP(BT_OGF_LE, 0x0032)
struct bt_hci_cp_le_set_phy {
    uint16_t  handle;
    uint8_t   all_phys;
    uint8_t   tx_phys;
    uint8_t   rx_phys;
    uint16_t  phy_opts;
} __packed;
```

You may for example connect, using bluetoothctl, an LE peripheral:

```
$ bluetoothctl
# connect 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

after the connection is established, you can get the connection handle with the command:

```
$ hcitool con
```

This is an example:

```
$ hcitool con
Connections:
    < LE F7:61:E5:21:DA:69 handle 16 state 1 lm MASTER
```

In this case, the handle had a value of 16.
Considering the above structure, we can prepare a raw command by sending a sequence of bytes that represents the values in each element of the structure, using Little Endian order:

```
$ sudo hcitool cmd 0x08 0x0032  0x10 0x00  0x00  0x02 0x02  0x00 0x00
```

The first two numbers are the command **BT_HCI_OP_LE_SET_PHY**.
After the command, a sequence of byte should be provided, representing the fields of struct **bt_hci_cp_le_set_phy**:

**0x10 0x00** are the 16 bit Handle, its value is 16, as reported by the "hcitool con" command.

**0x00** is the field "all_phys", bits 0 and 1 may mask TX and RX PHY. We want to set both, so 0 means that both values are indicated.

**0x02 0x02** are the TX and RX preferred PHY, in this case 2 means LE-2M.

This is the declaration inside hci.h:

```
#define BT_HCI_LE_PHY_PREFER_1M                 BIT(0)
#define BT_HCI_LE_PHY_PREFER_2M                 BIT(1)
#define BT_HCI_LE_PHY_PREFER_CODED              BIT(2)
```

The last two bytes **0x00 0x00** are the phy_opts field, its value is considered only when PHY is set to CODED.

This is the output of the btmon program after issuing the command (the btmon has been opened inside another console before issuing the command):

```
$ sudo btmon -T
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                                                             {0x0002} [hci0] 2023-03-04 12:42:40.943654
< HCI Command: LE Set PHY (0x08|0x0032) plen 7                                                               #4273 [hci0] 2023-03-04 12:42:40.943727
        Handle: 16
        All PHYs preference: 0x00
        TX PHYs preference: 0x02
          LE 2M
        RX PHYs preference: 0x02
          LE 2M
        PHY options preference: Reserved (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                    #4274 [hci0] 2023-03-04 12:42:40.945362
      LE Set PHY (0x08|0x0032) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
```

I hope this may be helpful for you and anyone with a similar problem.